# jQuery Click Function not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery Function on a site:

```
$('#CAT_Custom_381715_0').click(function () {
   $(".grow").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

What I am aiming for is when a checkbox is clicked it will then show other parts of the form.

The HTML code is below:

```
<tr>
  <td><label>Have You Grown This Plant?</label><br />
      <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="CAT_Custom_381715_0" />Yes</td>
</tr>

<tr class="grow"> <!-- FORM CODE --> </tr>
<tr class="grow"> <!-- FORM CODE --> </tr>
```

CSS for `.grow`

```
.grow{
  display:none;
}
```

I assume has something to do with the table causing the issue. No errors are thrown. I originally had a div wrapping the code but Firefox would remove the div. Not sure if that was Firefox or my CMS.

The problem is the `<tr>` with the class of `grow` does not show when the checkbox is clicked.

How do I get jQuery to work properly.

Comment: What's the problem? When clicked, this is going to show both of the tr's if they're not already shown. You have no conditional in place to handle toggling, so that's to be expected.

Comment: You had a `div` wrapping the `tr` elements?

Comment: @CrazyTrain - I did, yes.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I edited question. The problem is the checkbox when clicked doesn't show the hidden fields.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? Are you hitting the call to `.fadeIn()`? ***Edit:*** And do the HTML elements displayed by the debugger look right?

Comment: Browsers don't like showing/hiding `tr` elements.

Comment: @undefined what browsers? I'm genuinely interested to know.

Comment: @GreatBigBore - How do I see this in Firebug?

Comment: Is this behavior you are looking for? http://cdpn.io/jztKb

Comment: @kunalbhat - That worked. Put as an answer. I am baffled why my other code didn't work. I have used it before. A mystery in life...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched the click behavior to on and it is toggling. However, I also recommend you read this post and make sure to check to see if your checkbox is **actually checked**, and not just clicked on.

[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript?rq=1)

Here is the Codepen link: http://cdpn.io/jztKb

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Have You Grown This Plant?</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="CAT_Custom_381715_0" />Yes</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="grow"><td>Hi</td></tr>
  <tr class="grow"><td>Hi</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.grow {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#CAT_Custom_381715_0').on('click', function() {
   $(".grow").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```